# redirect htaccess except a folder

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, http-redirect

I try to redirect the whole website to an other domain, that is working !
But my case need that, if I tried to access to a subfolder (just one), I want to stay at this domain.

Here's my code

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !administrator

RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}   ^domaine.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)        http://www.domaine.fr/$1 [QSA,L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}    ^www.domaine.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)         http://www.domaine.fr/$1 [QSA,L,R=301]
```

This RewriteCond is working in an other project that I took.

So does someone have an idea ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`RewriteBase` line cannot come immediately after `RewriteCond`:

Just one rule will be enough for this task:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domaine\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ! administrator http://www.domaine.fr%{REQUEST_URI} [NC,L,R=301]
```